# CheckBox problems

Tags: java, swing, checkbox

I'm currently learning gui by myself, I'm having troubles with the JCheckBox. How can I make only one answer mark? currently, I can mark the two answers.
mt ideal is that the user could pick only one choice at a time, and if he picks the other one it deletes the pick of the first one.
can somebody help? thanks!

```
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.ItemEvent;
import java.awt.event.ItemListener;

import javax.swing.JCheckBox;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;


public class CheckBoxTry 
{
    JCheckBox show1,show2;
    JLabel label1, label2;
    private JFrame jf; 
    public CheckBoxTry(){
        jf= new JFrame();
        jf.setSize(300,300);
        jf.setVisible(true);
        jf.setLayout(new GridLayout(2,2));
        label1= new JLabel("");
        jf.add(label1);
        label2= new JLabel("");
        jf.add(label2);
        show1=new JCheckBox("show1");
        show2=new JCheckBox("show2");
        jf.add(show1);
        jf.add(show2);
        event e= new event();
        show1.addItemListener(e);
        show2.addItemListener(e);
    }
    public class event implements ItemListener{
        public void itemStateChanged (ItemEvent e){
            if (show1.isSelected())
            {
                label1.setText("1 selected");
            }else{
                label1.setText("");
            }

            if (show2.isSelected())
            {
                label2.setText("2 selected");
            }else{
                label2.setText("");
            }
        }
    }
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        CheckBoxTry as= new CheckBoxTry();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by using setSelected(boolean b) method to your checkboxes. However, in order to make them work together, you must kind of seperate their listeners.

```
@Override
    public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent e) {
        if (e.getSource() == show1) {
            if (show1.isSelected()) {
                label1.setText("1 selected");
                show2.setSelected(false); //remove selection from show2 and call again this item listener
            } else {
                label1.setText("");
            }
        } else if (e.getSource() == show2) {
            if (show2.isSelected()) {
                label2.setText("2 selected");
                show1.setSelected(false);//remove selection from show1 and call again this item listener
            } else {
                label2.setText("");
            }
        }
    }
```

Also a friendly remind is:

```
SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> {
            CheckBoxTry as = new CheckBoxTry(); // All swing apps must run on their own thread.
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

> mt ideal is that the user could pick only one choice at a time

You should be a `JRadioButton` for this instead of JCheckBox.

Then you add each `JRadioButton` to a `ButtonGroup` and the `ButtonGroup` will make sure only one button is ever selected.

Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Use Radio Buttons](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/button.html) for more information and working examples.